# Dynamic array v-bind class

Tags: multidimensional-array, vuejs2

I'm trying to set a class on items of which the value of a two-dimensional array is set to true. The array looks like this:

```
test[item][day]
```

And it get created and set in a method.

The template:

```
<div>
 <div v-for="item in items" class="item-row">
     <div class="item-name">item: {{ item.id }}</div>
     <div v-for="day in days" class="item-header" v-bind:class="{'activeDay' : test[item.id][day]}">{{ day }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This 'works', but I do get an error:

> vue.js?3de6:2902 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)

This is because the array gets filled in too late I guess? I set my array like: test[1][2] = 'true', but read somewhere I should be using Vue.set. However, I can't seem to get the right syntax to use it with a two-dimensional array.

Any advise on what the proper way is to achieve this?

Comment: what does test look like in your data object? Is it an empty array??

Comment: Yes I create it like test = [], and then in mounted() I call a method that fills it. Should I maybe do something wth nextTick? I just want the methods to run first, before the template renders. How do I do this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the issue seems to relate to the content not being populated when the component is rendered it is just a matter of controlling either when the template renders this 2d array, or when you populate its content.

**option 1**

If you have access to all the data the 2d array needs when the component is first created (i.e. no ajax requests for data going on). Then simply move the call to the method that builds the array into your components created method, i.e.

```
created () {
  this.buildItems()
},
...
```

**option 2**

If you need to request the data via ajax or for some other reason can not populate the array in the created method then just set a param to indicate when it is built and control its rendering, i.e.

```
# template
<div v-if="itemsReady" v-for="item in items" class="item-row">

# script
data () {
  return {
    itemsReady: false, // set to true when you have built the items array
    ...
  },
},
methods: {
  buildItems () {
    ... // logic to build array
    this.itemsReady = true
  },
  ...
},
```

Comment: did this sort it?

Comment: Clever solution! Thanks :)